# Q: Book Recommendation: Matrix Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, book-recommendation

I am taking a class in Matrix Algebra soon in Uni, and have heard from colleagues who were in that class that it is quite a tough course. I am looking to possibly do some self study prior to beginning the class. The class focuses on, as the name suggests, some of the following (taken directly from the description on the class webpage):

> **Matrix arithmetic:**
>
> - Addition
> - Multiplication
> - Transpose
>
> **Systems of linear equations:**
>
> - Solving SLEs
> - Gaussian elimination
> - Gauss-Jordan algorithm
>
> **Square matrices:**
>
> - Computing determinants
> - Invertibility
> - Computing inverses
> - Properties of determinants
> - Consistency theorems

To my understanding most of if not all of the aforementioned topics fall under Linear Algebra, however I'm hesistant on buying a book on the topic of Linear Algebra as I fear I may mistakingly learn "the wrong topics", in the sense that my study won't be applicable when I take the class. I'm looking for a book that covers most if not all the topics above, and more importantly in a fairly beginner friendly way, possibly with some exercises etc, as I should also mention that all of those topics are completely alien to me and I have never touched on them before in the slightest, naturally leading to some underconfidence.

Thank you for any recommendations.

Comment: Imo the most basic and user friendly way of learning linear algebra is from Friedberg insel and spence. The book already covers all of these topics separately without the need of learning things like "multilinear maps" before learning determinants. However couple this with Linear Algebra: A Matrix Approach by the same authors and I think you have a good match

Comment: If you don't already know the material in Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra, I'd recommend that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been teaching linear algebra for six years the best book that covers the concepts you mentioned is **Linear Algebra and Its Applications** for **David C. Lay**. And if you want a more slightly abstract book (useful for mathematicians) you can check **LINEAR ALGEBRA** for **Jim Hefferon**. The last book I would like to recommend is **Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler is an excellent book** which I have never used but there is a huge vote for it.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning of my book Linear Algebra Done Right. However, Linear Algebra Done Right is intended to be a textbook for a second course in linear algebra. It would not be a good fit for some of the matrix algebra topics listed in the original question. I do agree with you that the book by David Lay is a good choice for someone who has no experience with linear algebra.

Comment: @SheldonAxler you are a welcome professor. It is nice to see your comment on my post.